# Makefile is giving me an error - No such file or directory

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a *very* simple makefile. All I want to do in this makefile is compile my files and create an executable for my test. I have the following files:

- Test.cpp - main function
- BaseClass.cpp
- BaseClass.h - header file for the Base class
- DerivedClass.cpp - Inherits the base class
- DerivedClass.h - header file for the derived class

Here is the makefile I have:

```
all: Test

Test: BaseClass.o DerivedClass.o Test.o
    g++ -o BaseClass.o DerivedClass.o Test.o Test

Test.o: Test.cpp BaseClass.h DerivedClass.h
    g++ -c Test.cpp

Package.o: BaseClass.cpp BaseClass.h
    g++ -c BaseClass.cpp

DerivedClass.o: DerivedClass.cpp DerivedClass.h
    g++ -c DerivedClass.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

I've never created a makefile for 5 files before. I can create one with 3 pretty easily, but I don't know what's wrong. The error I'm getting is:

*Test: No fuch file or directory*

EDIT: Thanks, Joe! That was it. Pretty silly oversight of mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Test` should be the argument to `-o`:

```
Test: BaseClass.o DerivedClass.o Test.o
    g++ -o Test BaseClass.o DerivedClass.o Test.o
```

Notice I moved `Test` from the end of the line to immediately after `-o`.